# Using Portable Class Libaries in PlayStationStudio projects

Tags: .net, monodevelop, portable-class-library

I'm trying to reuse some portable code in PlayStationStudio projects right now.

I can reference the assemblies OK, and I can fill the gaps for missing methods using stub TypeForwarding assemblies.

However, the compiler is currently objecting about some of the "System" references in the Portable Class Libraries.

For example, if I try to include NewtonSoft JSON.Net, then I get errors like:

> c:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS\Cirrious\Cirrious.MvvmCross\Platform\Json\MvxDateTimeJsonConverter.cs(13,13): Error CS0012: The type 'System.Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'. (CS0012) (Cirrous.MvvmCross.PSS)

The PSS project already has a reference to System for 2.0.5.0, and that System assembly has a System.Uri in it, but the PublicKeyToken doesn't match - because it's a Sony assembly and not a Microsoft generated one.

Other than pulling all the portable libraries in as source and recompiling them to link to the Sony assemblies, can anyone think of any other solutions to this problem? e.g. is there some compiler or environment flag I can add?

Comment: PCL can only forward types to profiles that it knows about.  Which is currently Full, Silverlight, Phone and XBox.  It doesn't know anything about Sony specific assemblies.  You suppose you could technically add your own profile but it is a major effort to create the reference assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I've already added my own support for monodroid by mixing it into Profile 104 and adding some TypeForwarding for System.Net and System.Windows - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-portable-library-tools-for.html. I am intending (hoping?) to do the same for PSS and monotouch - but I can't see how I can get past this compiler level issue at present. If the PSS compiler insists on strongly signed assemblies, then I might be stuck :/

Comment: Microsoft designs PCL for its own, and I am not conviced that it can be used easily for Mono's all supported environments. You might continue the fight, but should be for experimental purposes. If for production, you should not play so hard.

Comment: @LexLi The BCL team have said they want to include Mono platforms - see the comments on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/01/19/announcing-portable-library-tools-ctp-justin-van-patten.aspx - and members of the Redmond PCL team have also been very helpful in answering some of my other MonoDroid-PCL questions. So I'm hoping to play hard for production :)

Comment: That's obviously good news, but not sure how Xamarin can work with Microsoft on this as the agreement between Novell and Microsoft no longer applies.

Comment: Update - I'm getting somewhere with some ildasm/ilasm hacking using code based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32639/Converting-NET-Assemblies-to-Silverlight-Assemblie